# How can I simplify verification that a method is called with certain parameters and no others?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I need two checks

```
verify(mock).method(any(Object.class));
verify(mock).method(object); // instance of Object...
```

to ensure the `method` is called exactly once with the certain parameter `object`, i.e. there is no second call `method(differentObject)` however I hope there is a way to simplify that I still don't know. Is this to uncommon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to simplify it, as far as I can tell. You *do* need to write the two `verify(mock).method(...)` calls. The only other ways would be to use an `ArgumentCaptor` or an `Answer`, but they are no simpler.

The use of `only()` (as suggested in another answer) does not work, as explained and exemplified in the [API documentation](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#only()) for this method.

Answer (score 3):

```
 verify(mock).method(object);
 verifyNoMoreInteractions(mock);
```

If I read you correctly you need to verify that the mock was called once and only once and that the single call had an argument equal to `object` (I am a little confused by your inclusion of `any(Object.class)` above). If so, this is very common and the above solution works well.

Another way you can do this in a more complicated situation is to use an `ArgumentCaptor`. This will grab all invocations and allow you to verify that the correct number of invocations were made and get each argument passed in order.

EDIT: To place Jan's comment / solution where is is more readable...

```
verify(mock, only()).someMethod();
```

The above verifies is exactly the same as the two calls of `verify` and `verifyNoMoreInteractions` above.

In order to verify that only one call was made to a method (with argument matching) and not do any verification of other method calls, try...

```
verify(mock).method(object);  // verify that there was one call matching
                              // the expected argument
verify(mock).method(any(Object.class)); // verify that there only one and only one call
```

The other mechanism is to use the `ArgumentCaptor` suggested.

Comment: I didn't know `verifyNoMoreInteractions`, so thank you for this lesson. But this is much to overspecified as stated in the javadoc of the method. I want to allow any other unverified calls, but not to `method`. Assume `verify(mock).method(any(Object.class));` is not there and the tested code calls `method(object) || method(differentObject)`. Then `verify(mock).method(object)` is fine. Only `verify(mock).method(any(Object.class))` will fail, as there are two calls to `method`, not only one. ArgumentCaptor would be much more bloat then my solution. Probably it is the best as I miss.

Comment: By the way I found `verify(mock, only()).someMethod();` as shortcut for your solution.

Comment: I didn't know about that one. Nice. Cheers!

Comment: @Rogério Thanks for the correction. Yes, according to the javadocs `only` is exactly the same as my original suggestion.

Comment: However, two calls to `verify` as I suggest at the end above should work nicely as well.

Comment: Both `verifyNoMoreInteractions(mock)` and `verify(mock, only()).someMethod()` don't work for me in most cases, because the mock has different interactions, which are NOT calls to `someMethod()`
(eg. the mock itself is used as a parameter in a method, which is apparently also an interaction)

Comment: @PKuijpers Mocks can only verify method calls made upon them. Passing around parameters (Objects) is just passing around a memory address. The verification of this would be upon the object upon which the mock was passed.